# how to rewrite the url in java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

On Form Submit my url changes from

1. **localhost:8080/Workflow/admin/GetReports?fname=Form1**

to

2. **localhost:8080/Workflow/admin/EditReport**

Form action is EditReport(Servlet Name).

Now on EditReport i perform the databse operations and forward the request to the ***GetReports?fname=Formname*** Servlet using Request Dispatcher.So that i am on the same page which is the first one (1) i started from.

Now Everything works fine on the ***.jsp*** page But the url remains unchanged that is the second one (2).

So how to rewrite the url i.e. from ***admin/EditReport*** to  ***/admin/GetReports?fname=Form1***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `dispatcher.forward` because you are setting some Attributes in 
the Request?

If not, then you don't need to use Forward. Instead of that, use `response.sendRedirect("url for GetReports?fname=Form1")`

But If you are setting some Attributes in the request, then I am wondering if your workflow is a correct one because URLs like this `"Workflow/admin/GetReports?fname=Form1"` should Not be arrived upon after doing some processing. They should be simple HTTP GET requests only.

Comment: It was the only attribute that i wanted to send ..so the response.sendRedirect did the job...